# Does anyone know what this hard pimple like bump is on my dogs back?

Tags: dogs

I noticed this hard pimple like bump on my dogs upper back about 6 months ago and it’s still there. She has another smaller one in her hip area as well. She is 3 years old in August so she is still very young to have bumps. however she saw a vet a few weeks ago and they told me it could be a non cancerous cyst(sebaceous cyst) it feels like a hard pimple with a tiny little scab on it. In addition she is full of Energy and acts normal. Just looking for a second opinion for a peace of mind .

Thank you 
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

From my experience I would concur with your vet - it looks just like the cysts I've seen on my dogs. Even though they're commonly thought of as "old dog lumps", dogs of any age can get them (Just like people of any age can get cysts). I have a boy right now who's had his cyst for going on 6 years (We noticed it when he was 5). His started out that size and is now the size of an engorged tick. As long as it's not bothering your pup, I wouldn't be worried!